# List of values as input to interactive plot

Tags: python, interactive, ipywidgets

I want some variable value to define the number of possible user inputs to an interactive plot. I have tried using ipywidgets, but no success. Below is a simple example of what i would like to do:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive

def p_(w1=1,w2=1,h1=1,h2=1):
    plt.bar([w1,w2], [h1,h2])
    
interactive_plot = interactive(p_,w1=(0,10,1),h1=(0,10,1),w2=(0,10,1),h2=(0,10,1))
interactive_plot
```

So this gives me two bars in the plot and I can change the width (w) and height (h) for each of them individually. However, I would like to rewrite this so that I do not need to manually add w1,w2,h1,h2 etc, since the number of variables might change. So the function should just be:

```
def p_(w,h):
    plt.bar(w,h)
```

But how do I communicate to the interactive plot how many variables are in w and h?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of interractive script to add data on an histogram.
I think you should try to use picker of matplotlib that offers a great liberty on what you can do insteed of ipywidgets.

(I know that is not the ideal answer for you but consider testing and reading the code below to evaluate the potential of pickers)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def picker(line, mouseevent):
    global datas
    
    if str(mouseevent.button).split(".")[-1] == "LEFT":
        datas[0].append(mouseevent.xdata)
        datas[1].append(mouseevent.ydata)
        update()
    return {}, False


def update():
    global bars
    bars.remove()
    bars = ax.bar(datas[0], datas[1], picker=picker, color="green")
    fig.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global bars
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    datas = [[3, 5, 2], [8, 6, 4]]
    bars = ax.bar(datas[0], datas[1], picker=picker, color="green")
    plt.show()
```